# Issue from spring-boot-dependencies 2.2.2.RELEASE related to org.quartz-scheduler:quartz

Tags: spring-boot, maven, quartz-scheduler

While building my project, I noticed WARNINGS such as:

```
    [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.openx.delivery.service:delivery_adserver_java:jar:170.1.2

    [WARNING] 'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.exclusions.exclusion.artifactId'
 for org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar with value '*' does not match a valid id pattern. @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.2.RELEASE, 
/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.2.2.RELEASE.pom, line 2753, column 25

    [WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

    [WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

There is no direct reference to `'org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar'` in my project.
I do no see also any reference to this module when I execute '`mvn dependency:tree`' also.

**Question**: how can i solve this problem

//edit

there are more details about my pom.xml"

```
...
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
...
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
      </dependency>
...
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- For old JUnit4 tests -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
...
```

Comment: Can you add the pom.xml you're using?

Comment: I cannot because of company regulation - but I will add more details to post

Comment: Based on the snippet I already can see you have a problem related to JUnit 4 and JUnit Jupiter ...If you like to run JUnit 4 tests you have to add JUnit Jupiter Vintage otherwise tests will not run...I strongly recommend to switch to JUnit Jupiter completely...furthermore why not using most recent version of Spring boot (2.2.6.RELEASE) and the message shows likely that you are using an old Maven version? Which. Maven version do you use? And the block with the exclusions is not shown in the snippet...?

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for comment - I know about this issue but t is intentionally in this project - I have a lot of old tests in JUnit 4 and I am introducing Spring Boot into legacy code and because of that I want to keep old tests and add new tests (Junit 5) - I am using both in the same time

Comment: Just remove JUnit.4 dependeny and add junit-jupiter-vintage makes it easier. So you can keep JUnit 4 tests in your code and migrate them over the time...